# how to save in a session variable an array extracted from a database to send it to other web pages in php

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have some data than I recoved from a database in a treatment page and than i try to send these data to other web pages by a session variable, like that :

```
while($enr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $_SESSION['med'] = $enr;

    header("location: recherche.php");

    //print_r($_SESSION['med']);
}
```

when I `print_r($_SESSION['med']);` in the processing page, I have an array like that :

```
Array ( [nom] => CASPER [prenom] => ARMAND ) 
Array ( [nom] => WILLIAMS [prenom] => GEORGE ) 
Array ( [nom] => VANASTEN [prenom] => ROBERT ) 
Array ( [nom] => MARTIN [prenom] => ALAIN ) 
Array ( [nom] => Jacque [prenom] => ERIC ) 
Array ( [nom] => LUCAS [prenom] => ANNIE )
```

But when I try to retrieve this array of data to other pages like that :

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['med'])) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['med'] as $champ) {
                echo "$champ -----";
            }
        } else {
            echo "no data";
        }
?>
```

I only have the last like that :

```
LUCAS -----ANNIE -----
```

So, how can I do to have all the data ?

Comment: Having that location header inside the loop makes very little sense, put it after.

Comment: You keep overriding the same session array key. Try `$_SESSION['med'][] = $enr;` and modify your output to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your print_r looked good is that you put into the loop. You rewrite the $_SESSION['med'] variable every row and the last row was your result what you get back when you print out your session later.

You should try this:

```
  while($enr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $_SESSION['med'][] = $enr;




    }
//print_r($_SESSION['med']);
header("location: recherche.php");
```

And then:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['med'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['med'] as $champ) {
            echo $champ['nom']." -----";
         }
 } else {
      echo "no data";
 }
```

Comment: But remove the `header()` as that makes no sense inside a loop